# Deleting data from multiple tables in a database

Tags: php, database, sql-delete

I've been trying to figure out how to delete data from multiple tables in a database. Just to give some background, there is a user table the holds basic information like first and last name. Then there is a login table that holds the passwords and usernames. I am making an admin page that allows me to see a user list with information from both tables. That part works fine. My problem is trying to create a delete script. 
I tried making separate queries, but I'm not getting anywhere. Can someone give me some direction? Or at least somewhere where I can read up on this specifically?

```
// Get IDs
$lid = $_POST['lid'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];

// Delete the product from the database
require_once('database.php');

$query = "DELETE user,login FROM user INNER JOIN login ON user.uid = '$uid' AND login.lid= '$lid'";
 $db->exec($query);
```

Comment: You can't do joins like that in a DELETE.  Just use two DELETE statements.

Comment: Use foreign keys that cascade, so when you delete an user, all related data to that user is automatically deleted as well

Comment: And remember, you don't have to do a hard delete. You can have a field in your table that records whether the record has been deleted. And when you do a delete, just update the value in the field. Maybe call the field deleted, and for a value of 0 it is active and for a value of 1 deleted. This way you can recover the data if you didn't mean to delete it.

Comment: I never thought of doing that. I think I will give that a try right now. Thanks Jolly!

Answer (score 2):

add a foreign key and then in your column definition use ON DELETE CASCADE which will take care of deleting the child row when parent row is deleted

Comment: +1 - That assumes, though, that the database being used supports foreign keys with cascade deletes (not all MySQL storage engines do, for example) and that there is a foreign key relationship between the tables-- the question doesn't include any predicates that indicate that both tables share a key.

Comment: Thank you so much! I read up on it and I understand. I got the code working.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the database (and possibly what constraints are in place) whether you can do this in a single DML statement.  The simpler option, though, would generally be to do something like this using two DML statements.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE user.uid = '$uid'";
$db->exec($query);
$query = "DELETE FROM login WHERE login.lid= '$lid'";
$db->exec($query);
```